# vert.x replication over a cluster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vert.x

I want to user vert.x to implement a socket server.

I will be using a cluster and I have one problem I can not figure out. If say I create a ConcurrentMap to store the socket connections on one [verticle](http://vertx.io/manual.html#verticle) and this is accessed by the other verticles on other clusters, what happens if the node that is running the first verticle with the ConurrentMap crashes? Obviously I would lose all connections in the ConcurrentMap. How would I replicate this ConcurrentMap so that one is always ready in-case of a crash? I have looked over the documentation and there does not seem to be a solution for replication. The only solution I can think of is whenever there is a new socket connection to insert it into the concurrentMap and also create an in-memory redis database and insert a new socket connection there everytime. This though seems like too much overkill and to recover could take a lot of time if there are a lot of connections (millions). Is there any easier way?

Comment: Please check your tags.  It looks like amazone* are irrelevant

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I forgot to mention that I am creating this cluster using amazon's ec2 instances